# How to list a view name used for creating a version on a branch (ex:0,1,2) in ClearCase

Tags: version-control, clearcase

In IBM Clearcase, I am trying to find the view name which was used to create a version on a branch. If I do version properties / Element properties I get information onto who created it but not the view name used to create that particular version.

Is there a quick cmd-prmpt way to find out which view was used on a particular version of a branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the view name of a checked-out version.

But not directly of a checked-in one.

Check the result of a [`cleartool lshist -minor`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm) and see if the event you see ([checkin, described in `events_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/events_ccase.htm) ) does include the view used to make the checkin.

Try it on the file:

```
cleartool lshist -minor aFile
```

Or on the branch:

```
cleartool lshistory -minor -branch rel2_bugfix
```

I don't think [`cleartool descr -l`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) would help directly.

As a last resort, check-out "[Identifying elements by the source container path](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234502)"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the name of the view used to create a checked-in version. If you feel the information is critical to retain, you can create a postop checkin trigger to append the view information to the checkin comment using cleartool chevent.

I think you may be "thinking git" where it may be critical to know which "remote" was used to create a commit.

In CC, after a checkin, the view private data/metadata associated with the checkout is removed from the view and VOB. What is the objective of retaining that information?